# Jquery Confirm Dialog in MVC 3.0

Tags: jquery

Greetings,

Is there any way to show JQuery Nice Confirm Dialog Box in MVC, which shows:
1. All the input fields content that user has filled.
2. Selected radio button value and name
3. Selected Checkboxes value and name

Once the user confirms 'Yes' commit to database else return back to form.

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a div which contains all your confirmation messages.

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation Dialog" style="display:none">Messages... </div>
```

Then initialize a dialog with the div id using following script.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                //Function call to commit to database
            },
            "No": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Karthi appreciate it. I'm MVC newbie, how is it possible to populate 'messages...' section & show dialog box when user clicks submit button?

Comment: do you want to populate messages dynamically? or else you can add them directly into the div. onclick of submit button call a javascript which will open the confirmation dialog. `function confirm(){ $(#dialog-confirm").dialog('open'); }`

Comment: Yep, I would like to dynamically populate messages (where messages are the check boxex, radio buttons and input fields that user have selected or entered).
Basically my requirement is to show everything that user entered in form and ask for confirmation. Is this possible in MVC + Jquery?